# Parsing data from json.loads(), in python

Tags: python, json

I'm attempting to analyze data from a website. I parsed the HTML to get the json data using json.loads().

```
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
```

So now I'm left with data which resembles the following:

```
data = """
{'aggregateRating': {'reviewCount': 1691, 
                     '@type'      : 'AggregateRating', 
                     'ratingValue': 4.0}, 
 'review': [{'reviewRating' : {'ratingValue': 5}, 
               'datePublished': '2017-10-31', 
               'description'  : "I had a chance to see the Lakers ...", 
               'author'       : 'Andre W.'}]
}
""""
```

I am interested in returning the 'ratingValue' integer from reviewRating in the 'review' array. When I run this script:

```
pd.DataFrame(data['review'], columns = ['reviewRating'])
```

I get this:

```
    reviewRating
0   {'ratingValue': 5}
```

Instead, I'm looking to get data in the form of:

```
    ratingValue
0   5
```

I've attempted various variations such as

```
pd.DataFrame(data['review'], columns = ['reviewRating']['ratingValue'])
pd.DataFrame(data['review'], columns = ['reviewRating'][['ratingValue']])
pd.DataFrame(data['review']['reviewRating'], columns = ['ratingValue'])
```

But I'm sure i don't understand the underlaying structure of the data, or pandas.

Thus, am I better off cleaning {'ratingValue': 5} as a string in order to be left with the integer of interest, or is there an easy way to create a DataFrame that has the integer value of 'ratingValue'?

Thanks.

Comment: you're making it look like if `data` was a `json` string whereas it's probably a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `json_normalize` from `pandas.io.json` you can create the dataframe directly from the json.

Using your sample data, I was able to output:

```
>>> frame = json_normalize(data)

     author datePublished                           description  \
0  Andre W.    2017-10-31  I had a chance to see the Lakers ...

   reviewRating.ratingValue
0                         5
```

And then you can access the rating value using:

`frame.at[0, 'reviewRating.ratingValue'] # which should give you 5`